# C programming recursion question generating segfault

Tags: c

trying to convert any number to any base in a recursion with C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* anybase(int n, int b)
{

   char * s;
   int len;

   if(n==0) {strcpy(s,""); return s;}

   s = anybase(n/b, b);

   len=strlen(s);
   s[len] = "0123456789ABCEDFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[n%b];
   s[len+1]='\0';
printf ("%s, %d, %d\n", s, n, b);

/*   return s; */


}
int main(){

char *s;

s = anybase(900000, 18);
/*printf ("%s, %d, %d\n", anybase(90000, 18), 90000, 18);*/

}
```

is it the recursion having a problem? not sure why one can't return a value in the function call. what would be needed to call this recursion function and return a value instead of void.

Why is it generating seg fault each time running it? Thanks!

Comment: `char *s` is pointing to nowhere in `anybase`, `strcpy(s,"");` is going to fail. You need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: You *must* return a value from the function: the recursing function and `main` both need it.

Comment: strcpy is not the problem

Comment: adding return to both anybase() and main() don't seem to avoid the seg fault

Comment: @user526427 Perhaps it fails at some other point, the main problem remains, that `char *s` does not point to a valid memory location. So your program is working under undefined behaviour: that means, sometimes crashes, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty much there, except you never allocated any memory for the string you're trying to produce. Here's a version which (apparently) runs correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* anybase(int n, int b)
  {
  char *s;
  int len;

  if(n == 0)
    {
    s = malloc(200);
    s[0] = '\0';
    }
  else
    {
    s = anybase(n/b, b);

    len=strlen(s);
    s[len] = "0123456789ABCEDFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[n%b];
    s[len+1]='\0';
    }

  return s;
  }

int main()
  {
  char *result;

  result = anybase(900000, 18);
  printf("%s\n", result);

  free(result);
  }
```

Note that since the buffer returned by `anybase` is allocated dynamically (using the `malloc` library function) it must be free'd after use.

Comment: not sure if one has to malloc - would defining char *s outside of the function anybase() work? making it a global variable and assign a value would sure give it some allocated memory location, right?

Comment: @user526427 check out my answer. It doesn't use malloc inside of your anybase function.

Answer (score 1):

The string buffer can be created statically in the main function but must then be passed to each recursive function call such that it can be written in to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 200
const char *selection = "0123456789ABCEDFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

void anybase(int n, int b, char *s)
{
    if (n) {
        anybase(n / b, b, s);

        strncat(&s[strlen(s)], &selection[n % b], sizeof(char));
        printf("%s, %d, %d\n", s, n, b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);

    anybase(900000, 18, buf);
    printf("Ouput: %s, N: %d, B: %d\n", buf, 90000, 18);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to avoid using malloc/calloc at all?

Comment: Then I would reccomend modifying your function `anybase` to accept a `char *` to a statically allocated char array in your main. You will no longer need to return the string as it will be passed through to each function call. I will edit my answer to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned the issue is `s` is just a pointer that points to no where.
But instead of allocating memory for `s` inside of your anybase function a better approach is to allocate the memory in the main function. This avoids possible memory leaks when calling the function multiple times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void anybase(int n, int b, char* s)
{
    int len;
    if(n==0) {strcpy(s,""); return;}

    anybase(n/b, b, s);

    len=strlen(s);
    s[len] = "0123456789ABCEDFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[n%b];
    s[len+1]='\0';
    printf ("%s, %d, %d\n", s, n, b);
    printf("%d\n", len +1);
    return;
}
int main(){
    char s[33]; /* enough for all ints with base 2 */
    anybase(90000, 18, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i saw this version of the code and not sure why it can't be using some return values. That's why i posted the first question

Comment: The reason why s is not a return value but an argument is because you want to pass in the array from outside. If you define the array inside your function it will be lost because of its scope. 
You could of course add a return value, but not sure what you would use it for.